# Using jQuery delay method to delay text

Tags: jquery, delay

I want to use the `.delay()` method to make a text appear after 3 seconds when a link(button) is clicked. I don't have much experience with jQuery so this might be very easy. Here is the code i was using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div.ico-productm').click(function(){
     $('div-fade1').delay(3000)
  });
});
```

It doesnt work this, do I need to use something else after the `.delay`, or reorder the functions somehow?

Comment: Does my solution fits your needs? If so then I would appreciate some points for this :)

Answer (score 1):

If `div-fade` is a class then add `.` if it is an `id` add `#` because there is no element `div-fade1`

Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div.ico-productm').click(function(){
    $('.div-fade1').delay(3000)
  });
});
```

Or maybe `fade1` is a `class` or an `id` the you can have something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('div.ico-productm').click(function(){
        $('div.fade1').delay(3000)
      });
    });
```